# running pip gives UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip, python-3.4

I just reinstalled python and pip, but when i run the command pip i should expect to see the help info for pip commands. instead i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  exec code in run_globals
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 210, in main
  cmd_name, cmd_args = parseopts(args)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 165, in parseopts
 parser.print_help()
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1670, in print_help
  file.write(self.format_help().encode(encoding, "replace"))
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1650, in format_help
  result.append(self.format_option_help(formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1633, in format_option_help
  result.append(group.format_help(formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1114, in format_help
  result += OptionContainer.format_help(self, formatter)
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1085, in format_help
  result.append(self.format_option_help(formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1074, in format_option_help
  result.append(formatter.format_option(option))
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 316, in format_option
  help_text = self.expand_default(option)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\baseparser.py", line 110, in expand_de
fault
  return optparse.IndentedHelpFormatter.expand_default(self, option)
File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 288, in expand_default
return option.help.replace(self.default_tag, str(default_value))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 11:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

i  have had python 3.4 installed before this but wanted to change to 2.7. on 3.4 pip were running fine, but there were some issues with django on python3.4

edit: user folder contains non-ascii character. This worked with python 3.4 but not with 2.7

Comment: Do you have a non-ASCII character in your filesystem or in your username?

Comment: Also, what version of pip is this? Run `pip -V`.

Comment: My users name in the filesystem have an ø in it. pip version 6.0.8

Comment: This is [issue 1713](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1713) in the issue tracker; it is marked as resolved but there has not yet been a new release of pip.

Comment: Correction; there are other bug reports that state the issue is still there, as you discovered. So it is a known bug, and the developers are working to remedy it.

Comment: It worked fine on python 3.4. Would making a new user fix this issue?

Comment: Or just use Python 3.4 to do your programming - why do you want to downgrade your python?

Comment: @Seagulltown: the error is caused only on Python 2, because your username contains non-ascii characters one of the default values for a command line option fails to interpolate correctly.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: The commands for starting a new django project didn't work with 3.4. As I am following a tutorial based on 2.7 and since i'm completely new to python downgrading seemed to be the only solution.

Comment: There is no significant difference with Django development

Comment: Can you share a link to the actual tutorial. You being new to Python means to me that you shouldn't have any reason to use 2.7 either.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhevHKBy7Hc  is what i used to get django up and running. 

I started out learning python with this tutorial     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8GpOeecPuU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a new user with ascii compliant characters. Pip now works fine with no errors.